# iteratively calling pandas datareader

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python dict with a list of stocks. I seek to use the keys (the stock symbol, see below) in a for loop to iteratively make multiple pandas DataFrames for all stocks (named for the stock symbol) that is filled with price/volume via the pandas DataReader. 
I think I have a basic python issue in code below because the only DataFrame that gets created is "stockName".
  Thanks for your help

```
print stocks.keys()
['TSO', 'WDC', 'EBIX', 'AAPL', 'GTAT', 'MSFT', 'BKE', 'VFSTX', 'ORCL', 'UIS', 'HSII', 'PETS', 'BBBY', 'RPXC', 'TZOO', 'DLB', 'SPLS', 'CHE', 'INTC', 'CF', 'GTN', 'FFIV', 'ATML', 'BAH', 'DHX', 'HRB', 'VIAB', 'LMT', 'NOC', 'VWO', 'ROST']

for stockName in stocks.keys():
    stockName = DataReader(stockName,  "yahoo", datetime(2013,1,1), datetime(2013,8,1))
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're only iterating over stocks you can call it directly with `stocks`

```
DataReader(stocks, 'yahoo', datetime(2013, 1, 1), datetime(2013, 8, 1))
```

You don't need to iterate since `get_data_yahoo` does that for you. You'll get back a `Panel` which you can use like a `dict` of `DataFrame`s. You don't even need to call `stocks.keys()` since

```
for key in dict(a=1, b=2, c=3):
    print key
```

will print

```
a
b
c
```

Here's the result:

```
In [3]: p = DataReader(stocks, 'yahoo', datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1), datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 1))

In [4]: p
Out[4]:
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 6 (items) x 147 (major_axis) x 31 (minor_axis)
Items axis: Open to Adj Close
Major_axis axis: 2013-01-02 00:00:00 to 2013-08-01 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: AAPL to WDC
```

If you want to be able to access the stock symbols via attribute access do

```
In [7]: p.swapaxes('items', 'minor').AAPL
Out[7]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 147 entries, 2013-01-02 00:00:00 to 2013-08-01 00:00:00
Data columns (total 6 columns):
Open         147  non-null values
High         147  non-null values
Low          147  non-null values
Close        147  non-null values
Volume       147  non-null values
Adj Close    147  non-null values
dtypes: float64(6)
```

**EDIT:** It's going to be *much* easier to manipulate the resulting `Panel` than to fill a `dict` and do something with that.

There's all sorts of fun stuff you could do with this. Here's the percent change grouped by `metric`, `stock`, and `date`:

```
In [127]: df = p.to_frame(filter_observations=False)

In [128]: res = df.stack().reset_index()

In [129]: res.columns = ['date', 'metric', 'stock', 'value']

In [130]: res.set_index('date').groupby(['metric', 'stock']).apply(lambda x: x.value.pct_change()).stack()
Out[130]:
metric     stock  date
Adj Close  AAPL   2013-01-03   -0.013
                  2013-01-04   -0.028
                  2013-01-07   -0.006
                  2013-01-08    0.003
                  2013-01-09   -0.016
                  2013-01-10    0.012
                  2013-01-11   -0.006
                  2013-01-14   -0.036
                  2013-01-15   -0.032
                  2013-01-16    0.042
                  2013-01-17   -0.007
                  2013-01-18   -0.005
                  2013-01-22    0.010
                  2013-01-23    0.018
                  2013-01-24   -0.124
...
Volume  WDC    2013-07-12   -0.083
               2013-07-15   -0.179
               2013-07-16   -0.302
               2013-07-17   -0.168
               2013-07-18    0.589
               2013-07-19    0.003
               2013-07-22    0.049
               2013-07-23    0.526
               2013-07-24    0.176
               2013-07-25    0.616
               2013-07-26   -0.363
               2013-07-29   -0.357
               2013-07-30    0.554
               2013-07-31   -0.252
               2013-08-01   -0.158
Length: 27010, dtype: float64
```

The sky is the limit with `pandas`!

Answer (score 4):

stockName is a variable that loops on the stock ticker list. It contains the ticker string. When you assign the DataFrame to it, this DataFrame is lost at the next turn of the `for` loop.

Create another variable, a `dict` for instance, where you assign the stock data into:

```
stockdata = {}
for stockName in stocks:
    stockdata[stockName] = DataReader(stockName,  "yahoo", datetime(2013,1,1), datetime(2013,8,1))
```