# Import data headers from excel doc, search web using pandas, then export to specific row/column in same excel doc

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to figure out how to import data from a particular excel sheet, search yahoo finance for information according to that data, then print the data received via yahoo (via pandas web.datareader) to a specific row/column in that same excel file.

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't accomplish what I'm setting out to do. This searches for information based off of inputs within the code, not inputs from an excel sheet, and exports the concatenated dataframe to a newly created spreadsheet, not a pre-existing one's specific row and columns.

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

start = dt.datetime.strptime("8/11/2017", "%m/%d/%Y")
end = dt.datetime.today()
headerlist = ('stock1 Open', 'stock1 Close', 'stock2 Open', 'stock2 Close', 
'stock3 Open', 'stock3 Close', 'stock4 Open', 'stock4 Close')

df1 = web.DataReader('stock1', 'yahoo', start, end)[['Open','Close']]
df2 = web.DataReader('stock2', 'yahoo', start, end)[['Open','Close']]
df3 = web.DataReader('stock3', 'yahoo', start, end)[['Open','Close']]
df4 = web.DataReader('stock4', 'yahoo', start, end)[['Open','Close']]

resultingdf = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4], axis=1)
resultingdf.to_csv('Portfolio.csv', header = headerlist)
```

Any help or direction would be greatly greatly appreciated.

Edit:

The code provided above runs fine, it just isn't achieving the goal that I am setting out for as it is not automated in the least. It requires a ton of inputs in the code itself. Here is a general breakdown of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
#import any other modules I may need

#establish timeframe
start = dt.datetime.strptime("8/11/2017", "%m/%d/%Y")
end = dt.datetime.today()

#search a pre-existing excel sheet's columns for stock tickers similar to: 
Name
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD

#use panda's datareader to find the information for those tickers from yahoo, google, etc.

#concat. the dataframe

#export the dataframe to a specific row and column in the same excel sheet similar to (with identifying header):
Open   High   Low   Close,   Open   High   Low   Close
```

Hope that explains it a little bit better.

Comment: In your code you don't import anything from excel. You also export resulting df to csv and not excel. Please provide the output received, the error received if any and the expected output. Hint: you xlrd to open excel files, or pd.ExcelFile to create a dataframe from the data. Use pd.ExcelWriter(name.xlsx, engine='openpyxl') to write back to same excel

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I am aware I'm not importing or exporting anything from excel currently. The code I provided is a substitute for what I'm trying to do (which is import from excel and the export to same excel sheet).

Comment: @user8834780, edited my original post to include a more detailed explanation of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from openpyxl import load_workbook

start = dt.datetime.strptime("8/11/2017", "%m/%d/%Y")
end = dt.datetime.today()

data_file = pd.ExcelFile('Stocks.xlsx',header=0).parse('Sheet1') #1st sheet
#print(data_file)

#datafile.columns is the excel's header row with stock 1, stock 2, etc. For example: FB, AAPL, etc.
stocks = web.DataReader(data_file.columns, 'yahoo', start, end)[['Open','Close']] #This creates a panel
#print(stocks)

#Writes to same workbookbook with data, but different tabs, where each column (Open, Close) is in a differen tab
#You can't "append" data to an existing sheet, only overwrite it in full including headers- so can't reuse next day
book = load_workbook('Stocks.xlsx')
writer= pd.ExcelWriter('Stocks.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
stocks.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```

Alternatively, you can create new excel with results, where each column (Open, Close) is in a different tab:

```
writer= pd.ExcelWriter('Stock Data.xlsx', engine="xlsxwriter")
stocks.to_excel(writer) #,index=False)
writer.save()
```

You can even create a new file with new data every day you run it, by specifying `name +'xslx'` in `pd.ExcelWriter` where

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
name = 'Opportunistic_leads_' + str(now)[:10]
```

Take a look here: [iteratively calling pandas datareader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363183/iteratively-calling-pandas-datareader) at some ways to transform output of `stocks`. This will apply when you export the panel to excel.

Note that I wasn't able to find a way to append data to an existing excel sheet without overwriting it, but this is as close to what you want as I could do it.

FYI, when you export a Panel (which is resulted from DataReader) to excel, it creates each "column" in a new tab as per https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.to_excel.html:

Comment: I am completely okay with the output being overwritten every time it's ran, so as long as it is overwriting its own previous output and nothing else, if that makes sense. Also, getting an error where it states it doesn't recognize symbol 'Name',etc. I have tons of other information on the spreadsheet, so it can't read the entire sheet, just the column, and it can't read the entire column, it should start on a certain row and go from there. If I delete everything else in the sheet it will run like a charm. Thanks a TON in advance for your help user8834780. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The way it is set up, it is expecting an excel file where header row includes the tickers, (starting cell A1) ie. AAPL, FB, etc. Nothing else. It will then do its magic and outputs the data to a new tab in that excel sheet. Or I provided an option for it to output data into a new excel sheet all together. In both these options, every time you run it, it will overwrite all previous results. I also gave option to have data come into a new excel file every time you run it on a different day. That's all you need- there are no errors on my side, I ran it successfully with sample data.

Comment: Again to reiterate, you can't write to the sheet that has the list of tickers (in my version) because when data is written to the original workbook, it overwrites data in that sheet in full; appending data to pre-existing data (like header) is not possible. You can look here how to append to existing sheets without losing data or formatting, but that's not as straight forward as my simple answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46308530/connect-pandas-output-to-excel-sheet-via-odbc This should give you everything you need. If it was helpful please upvote; if answer satisfactory then accept

Comment: Not enough rep for the upvote to show publicly, but it was recorded. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Just an FYI, I got the rep for the upvote so there it is! Thanks for all your help a while back!